# Visual Studio C++, breakpoints not stopping debugging DLL (GODOT GDExtention)

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-c++, scons, godot4

In short, all compiles and runs but breakpoints not getting hit.
I am using VC++ 2022. I am following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8I_G-3Nii4k&ab_channel=MichaelJared).

Invoking: `scons -j4 target=template_debug dev_build=yes debug_symbols=yes`

All DLLs and lib complied with dev.debug:

[image: ![image|485x500](upload://7LOe2cfD8VYpFHboBkMB31Ay1iK.png)]

The launch.vs.json

```
{
  "version": "0.2.1",
  "defaults": {},
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "default",
      "project": "C:\\dev\\my\\godot\\Godot_v4.2.1-stable_win64.exe\\Godot_v4.2.1-stable_win64_console.exe",
      "name": "Godot Game",
      "args": [
        "--path",
        "C:\\dev\\my\\godot\\godotcpp\\test1\\godot-cpp-template\\demo"
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "default",
      "project": "C:\\dev\\my\\godot\\Godot_v4.2.1-stable_win64.exe\\Godot_v4.2.1-stable_win64_console.exe",
      "name": "Godot Editor",
      "args": [
        "-e C:\\dev\\my\\godot\\godotcpp\\test1\\godot-cpp-template\\demo\\project.godot"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

And do start the scene from the editor. The breakpoint doesn't get hit
and looks like this:

[image]

### Update

Here is the pdb file:

[image]

Looks like total mess, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are missing the program database (PDB files).
You have to invoke the linker with the /DEBUG option.
Since you are using SCons - you have the edit your configuration file and add the /DEBUG linker options.

Answer (score 0):

SCons does support generating the PDB files, however you must enable it by setting env['PDB']

`env['PDB'] = "${TARGET.base}.pdb"`

Should likely do the job (I've not tried this)

From the SCons manpage:

> The Microsoft Visual C++ PDB file that will store debugging
> information for object files, shared libraries, and programs. This
> variable is ignored by tools other than Microsoft Visual C++. When
> this variable is defined SCons will add options to the compiler and
> linker command line to cause them to generate external debugging
> information, and will also set up the dependencies for the PDB file.
> Example:
>
> env['PDB'] = 'hello.pdb' The Microsoft Visual C++ compiler switch that
> SCons uses by default to generate PDB information is /Z7. This works
> correctly with parallel (-j) builds because it embeds the debug
> information in the intermediate object files, as opposed to sharing a
> single PDB file between multiple object files. This is also the only
> way to get debug information embedded into a static library. Using the
> /Zi instead may yield improved link-time performance, although
> parallel builds will no longer work. You can generate PDB files with
> the /Zi switch by overriding the default $CCPDBFLAGS variable; see the
> entry for that variable for specific examples.

See:

- https://scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-man.html#cv-PDB
- https://scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-man.html#cv-CCPDBFLAGS